# How to send ZIP file with post.request in python?

Tags: python, post, request, zip

I want to send ZIP file with request.post.

My code:

```
f = open("file.zip", 'rb')

files = {

    "message": f

}

result = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I'm trying with this code but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests - Post a zip file with multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208109/python-requests-post-a-zip-file-with-multipart-form-data)