# Python Rest client api to upload a file

Tags: python, rest, api, upload

I am using Python 2.7. My Rest server side API works fine and I am able to upload a zip file using Postman. I am trying to upload a zip file using Rest client api. I tried requests package, but it is unable to send the files. I am getting an error : missing file argument.

This is my python server side code :

```
@ns.route('/upload_file', strict_slashes=False)
class Upload(Resource):
    @api.expect(upload_parser)
    def post(self):

        args = upload_parser.parse_args()
        file_nameup = args.file.filename
```

Here is the rest api client code :

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

headers={'Username': 'abc@gmail.com', 'apikey':'123-e01b', 'Content-Type':'application/zip'}
f = open('C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/abc.zip', 'rb')

files = {"file": f}

resp = requests.post("https://.../analytics/upload_file", files=files, headers=headers )

print resp.text   

print "status code " + str(resp.status_code)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    print ("Success")
    print resp.json()
else:
    print ("Failure")
```

This is my error :
    {"message":"Input payload validation failed","errors":{"file":"Missing required
    parameter in an uploaded file"}
    status code 400
    Failure

In postman, I passed a zip file with in body with "file" as key and value as abc.zip file. It worked fine.  I tried to use httplib library, but it fails as my post url does not contain port number. This the error with httplib :

> python HttpClientEx.py
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "HttpClientEx.py", line 4, in 
>           h = http.client.HTTPConnection(url)
>         File "c:\python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 736, in **init**
>           (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
>         File "c:\python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 777, in _get_hostport
>           raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
>       httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '// ....net/analytics/upload_file'

How to invoke rest url post and upload a file using urllib library. Please suggest any other ways to upload file in rest client. Thanks.

I found another duplicate post :

[Python Requests - Post a zip file with multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208109/python-requests-post-a-zip-file-with-multipart-form-data)

The solution mentioned there did not work. I found that you need to provide the full path of the file, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests - Post a zip file with multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208109/python-requests-post-a-zip-file-with-multipart-form-data)

Comment: The solution mentioned there did not work. I found that you need to provide the full path of the file, otherwise it will not work. 

example: 
files = {"file": ("C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/abc.zip", f)}

if I specify 
files = {"file": ("abc.zip", f)}, its not working. Even though my program and zip are in the same folder.

Comment: ***to provide the full path***: This makes no sense. The first parameter in the `tuple` is used from the server, how to name the uploaded file. I could not imagin how a **local** path are usefull for a server at all. ***its not working***: This is not helpfull, [edit] your Question and show requests header and `result.json()` you get.

Comment: 'file' is the parameter name referred in my server rest api code. Refer python server side code above:
file_nameup = args.file.filename

What you said is correct. Somehow, the api requires a full path of zip file path, thats why I took long time to find the issue.  This is my result :

{"message": "File uploaded successfully", "file_ids": "123.zip"}

Answer (score 5):

Use urllib3 module.

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

**Files & binary data**

For uploading files using multipart/form-data encoding you can use the same approach as Form data and specify the file field as a tuple of (file_name, file_data):

```
with open('example.txt') as fp:
    file_data = fp.read()
r = http.request(
    'POST',
    'http://httpbin.org/post',
    fields={ 
        'filefield': ('example.txt', file_data),
    })

json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))['files']
```

Comment: It's just an example pulled from the site.  You would need to modify it for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

requests library worked with below changes in my code :

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
from pathlib import Path

file_ids = ''
headers={'Username': 'abc@gmail.com', 'apikey':'123-456'}
# Upload file

f = open('C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/abc.zip', 'rb')

files = {"file": ("C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/abc.zip", f)}

resp = requests.post("https:// ../analytics/upload_file", files=files, headers=headers )
print resp.text
print "status code " + str(resp.status_code)

if resp.status_code == 201:
    print ("Success")
    data = json.loads(resp.text)
    file_ids = data['file_ids']
    print file_ids
else:
    print ("Failure")
```

Comment: Here, note I removed Content-Type from my header, also I am providing full file name with path in  

files = {"file": ("C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/abc.zip", f)}